# Not able to play youtube videos in background on iOS, using YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

In my iOS app, I'm playing youtube videos using **YTPlayerView** (see [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) link for information), but video playback pauses if app has entered background. I would like to continue playing videos in background, I added "Audio and AirPlay" to "Required background modes" and set audio session in application delegate this way:

```
- (void) setAudioSession
{
    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    if (setCategoryErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting Audio Session Category Error: %@",[setCategoryErr description]);
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
    if (activationErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"Activating Audio Session Error: %@",[activationErr description]);
    }
}
```

but however video pauses when app enters background. What else should I do to make it work?

Comment: Hello Radu, did you ever figure this out? Please update us if you found a solution.

Comment: Radu, can you please update?

Comment: @RoiMulia Still no solution found (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many investigations, I've found that it's not possible. The following comment on this issue explains why:

> Technically speaking YouTube is a VIDEO streaming service so naturally
>   the video must be visible in order to also hear the audio. Therefore,
>   entering background mode should also stop the video playback.
>
> In order to comply with YouTube TOS and Apple guidelines you need to
>   display the video - and stop it from playing when locking the screen.
>   Sadly, no background playback of YouTube videos.